# Telegram bot php problem with 'option' array in sendPoll

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I don't know how to get working the code, probably i have an error writting the 'options' array. Code attached. I use the same elseif for `"sendMessage"` and works perfect. Thanks!

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendpoll

`'options' => array('A','B','C'),`

This is not working too

`'options' => [ "A", "B", "C" ]`

elseif (strpos($text, "/poll") === 0) {

```
    $parameters2 = array(
        'chat_id' => $chatId,
        'options' => array('A','B','C'),
        'question' => "Select correct one",

    );

    sendButton('sendPoll', $parameters);
```

}

Comment: The code you posted works fine. Have a look at error logs. Maybe you are tryiing to do a poll outside of group? Will only work in group chat. No private chat supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code

```
'options' => json_encode(array('A','B','C')),
```

in place of

```
 'options' => array('A','B','C'),
```